# Matplotlib, avoid update mouse cursor when draw

Tags: python, matplotlib, mouse

When a plot is updated with the `set_data` and `draw` method, the mouse cursor change few milliseconds from an arrow to a circle. Is it possible to avoid this? Because I update my plot 10 times per second so it is very ugly to see my mouse cursor change so quickly.

I am using Python 3.6, PyQt5, and matplotlib 2.1. Thank you in advance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution : use `QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()` when I leave the axe and `QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))` when I enter in it. Something like this so:

```
self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect("axes_enter_event", self.figureEntree)
self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect("axes_leave_event", self.figureSortie)
def figureSortie(self, event):
   QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
def figureEntree(self, event):
   QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))
```

And it is possible to adapt the `figureEntree` function if you have a toolbar (change the cursor along the tool active => variables which change when you select a tool).

Comment: For those looking for the full comand:
QtGui.QGuiApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor)) .
Using other cursors such as "QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor" is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is a new "feature" of matplotlib 2.1.

The [what's new page](https://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#busy-cursor) says

> Busy Cursor
>
> The interactive GUI backends will now change the cursor to busy when Matplotlib is rendering the canvas.

There is also [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9546) about the undesired behaviour.

Comment: It seems the above is not true for "TkAgg" backend, so using "TK" may be an option.

Comment: I have not the time to change the library for my plots so I have to live with this new feature even if I think, if it was not implemented before, there is a way to desactivate the busy cursor. Thank you for this information.

Comment: I will see if I find a solution later on.

Comment: I found a solution : use `QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()` when I leave the axe (event `axes_leave_event`), and `QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))` when I enter (event `axes_enter_event`)

Comment: Great. Just provide that as an answer yourself.